# AQL Query Really Slow (~20 seconds)

Tags: arangodb, aql

The following query is taking around **20 seconds** to execute:

```
FOR p IN PATHS(locations, connections, "outbound", { maxLength: 1 }) FILTER p.source._key == "26094" RETURN p.vertices[*].name
```

I believe this is a simple query (and the database is not that big) and it should execute fairly quick... I must be doing something wrong... Here is the query result:

```
==> [object ArangoQueryCursor - count: 286, hasMore: false]
```

The `locations` (vertices) collection has 23753 documents, and the `connections` (edges) collection has 123414 documents.

I tried to filter by `_id` as well but the performance is somewhat the same.

**Is there anything I could do to get a better performance?**

Here is the query's `.explain()` report:

```
 { 
  "plan" : { 
    "nodes" : [ 
      { 
        "type" : "SingletonNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ ], 
        "id" : 1, 
        "estimatedCost" : 1, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 1 
      }, 
      { 
        "type" : "CalculationNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ 
          1 
        ], 
        "id" : 2, 
        "estimatedCost" : 2, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 1, 
        "expression" : { 
          "type" : "function call", 
          "name" : "PATHS", 
          "subNodes" : [ 
            { 
              "type" : "array", 
              "subNodes" : [ 
                { 
                  "type" : "collection", 
                  "name" : "locations" 
                }, 
                { 
                  "type" : "collection", 
                  "name" : "connections" 
                }, 
                { 
                  "type" : "value", 
                  "value" : "outbound" 
                }, 
                { 
                  "type" : "object", 
                  "subNodes" : [ 
                    { 
                      "type" : "object element", 
                      "name" : "maxLength", 
                      "subNodes" : [ 
                        { 
                          "type" : "value", 
                          "value" : 1 
                        } 
                      ] 
                    } 
                  ] 
                } 
              ] 
            } 
          ] 
        }, 
        "outVariable" : { 
          "id" : 2, 
          "name" : "2" 
        }, 
        "canThrow" : true 
      }, 
      { 
        "type" : "EnumerateListNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ 
          2 
        ], 
        "id" : 3, 
        "estimatedCost" : 102, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 100, 
        "inVariable" : { 
          "id" : 2, 
          "name" : "2" 
        }, 
        "outVariable" : { 
          "id" : 0, 
          "name" : "p" 
        } 
      }, 
      { 
        "type" : "CalculationNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ 
          3 
        ], 
        "id" : 4, 
        "estimatedCost" : 202, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 100, 
        "expression" : { 
          "type" : "compare ==", 
          "subNodes" : [ 
            { 
              "type" : "attribute access", 
              "name" : "_key", 
              "subNodes" : [ 
                { 
                  "type" : "attribute access", 
                  "name" : "source", 
                  "subNodes" : [ 
                    { 
                      "type" : "reference", 
                      "name" : "p", 
                      "id" : 0 
                    } 
                  ] 
                } 
              ] 
            }, 
            { 
              "type" : "value", 
              "value" : "26094" 
            } 
          ] 
        }, 
        "outVariable" : { 
          "id" : 3, 
          "name" : "3" 
        }, 
        "canThrow" : false 
      }, 
      { 
        "type" : "FilterNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ 
          4 
        ], 
        "id" : 5, 
        "estimatedCost" : 302, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 100, 
        "inVariable" : { 
          "id" : 3, 
          "name" : "3" 
        } 
      }, 
      { 
        "type" : "CalculationNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ 
          5 
        ], 
        "id" : 6, 
        "estimatedCost" : 402, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 100, 
        "expression" : { 
          "type" : "expand", 
          "subNodes" : [ 
            { 
              "type" : "iterator", 
              "subNodes" : [ 
                { 
                  "type" : "variable", 
                  "name" : "1_", 
                  "id" : 1 
                }, 
                { 
                  "type" : "attribute access", 
                  "name" : "vertices", 
                  "subNodes" : [ 
                    { 
                      "type" : "reference", 
                      "name" : "p", 
                      "id" : 0 
                    } 
                  ] 
                } 
              ] 
            }, 
            { 
              "type" : "attribute access", 
              "name" : "name", 
              "subNodes" : [ 
                { 
                  "type" : "reference", 
                  "name" : "1_", 
                  "id" : 1 
                } 
              ] 
            } 
          ] 
        }, 
        "outVariable" : { 
          "id" : 4, 
          "name" : "4" 
        }, 
        "canThrow" : false 
      }, 
      { 
        "type" : "ReturnNode", 
        "dependencies" : [ 
          6 
        ], 
        "id" : 7, 
        "estimatedCost" : 502, 
        "estimatedNrItems" : 100, 
        "inVariable" : { 
          "id" : 4, 
          "name" : "4" 
        } 
      } 
    ], 
    "rules" : [ 
      "move-calculations-up", 
      "move-filters-up", 
      "move-calculations-up-2", 
      "move-filters-up-2" 
    ], 
    "collections" : [ 
      { 
        "name" : "connections", 
        "type" : "read" 
      }, 
      { 
        "name" : "locations", 
        "type" : "read" 
      } 
    ], 
    "variables" : [ 
      { 
        "id" : 0, 
        "name" : "p" 
      }, 
      { 
        "id" : 1, 
        "name" : "1_" 
      }, 
      { 
        "id" : 2, 
        "name" : "2" 
      }, 
      { 
        "id" : 3, 
        "name" : "3" 
      }, 
      { 
        "id" : 4, 
        "name" : "4" 
      } 
    ], 
    "estimatedCost" : 502, 
    "estimatedNrItems" : 100 
  }, 
  "warnings" : [ ], 
  "stats" : { 
    "rulesExecuted" : 21, 
    "rulesSkipped" : 0, 
    "plansCreated" : 1 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PATHS()` will build all paths of the graph and then post-filter the results using the `FILTER` on the `_key` attribute. This may create a huge result set first (for all paths) before filtering out all non-matches.

If all that's required is to find connected vertices on depth 1, I think it will be more efficient to do something like this:

- querying using `TRAVERSAL`:

  This is more efficient because it will build all paths in the graph but only those starting at the specified start vertex:

  ```
  FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(locations, connections, "1", "outbound", { minDepth: 1, maxDepth: 1, paths: true }) 
    RETURN p.path.vertices[*].name
  ```
- querying direct neighbors using `NEIGHBORS`:

  This may be slightly more efficient even because it will construct a smaller intermediate result.
  Additionally, it won't return the start vertex (26094) but all vertices directly connected to it:

  ```
  FOR p IN NEIGHBORS(locations, connections, "26094", "outbound") 
    RETURN p.vertex.name
  ```
- querying the edges directly (not using graph functions)

  Finally you can query the edge collection directly.
  Again, this won't return the start vertex (26094) but all vertices directly connected to it:

  ```
  FOR edge IN connections
    FILTER edge._from == "locations/26094"
    FOR vertex IN locations
      FILTER vertex._id == edge._to
      RETURN vertex.name
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All I need is to get all the possible paths between 2 vertices (ex. X and Y) with maxDepth = 2. I tried with TRAVERSAL but still taking around 10 seconds to execute. Here is the query : `FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(locations, connections, "X", "outbound", { minDepth: 1, maxDepth: 2, paths: true }) 
  FILTER p.destination._key == "Y"
  RETURN p.path.vertices[*].name`

Comment: Is there a faster and better way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've created another question with this new requirement to make it easier for other people with the same issue to find : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677086/arangodb-how-to-get-all-the-possible-paths-between-2-vertices