# ArangoDB : How to get all the possible paths between 2 vertices?

Tags: arangodb, aql

**How to get all the possible paths between 2 vertices (eg. X and Y) with maxDepth = 2?**

I tried with `TRAVERSAL` but it is taking around 10 seconds to execute. Here is the query :

```
FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(locations, connections, "X", "outbound", { minDepth: 1, maxDepth: 2, paths: true }) 
FILTER p.destination._key == "Y" 
RETURN p.path.vertices[*].name
```

The locations (vertices) collection has 23753 documents, and the connections (edges) collection has 123414 documents.

Comment: Where is the documentation to this `TRAVERSAL` function. Not able to find it anywhere. Can you please help me out?
Is this for 2.8??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up the query a lot if you put the filter for destination right into Traversal via the options `filterVertices` to give examples of vertices that should be touched by the traversal. With `vertexFilterMethod` you can define what should happen with all vertices that do not match the example.

So in your query you only want to match the target vertex "Y" and all other vertices should be passed through but not included in the result, `exclude`.

This makes the later FILTER obsolete.
Right now the internal optimizer is not able to do that automagically but this magic is on our roadmap.

This is a query containing the optimization:

```
FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(locations, connections, "X", "outbound", { minDepth: 1, maxDepth: 2, paths: true, filterVertices: [{_key: "Y"}], vertexFilterMethod: ["exclude"]})
RETURN p.path.vertices[*].name
```

Comment: That worked but the query is still taking ~5 seconds to execute, knowing that we are restricting the query to one single origin (X), and maxDepth of 2, I was expecting something faster for such small collections. But thanks a  lot for your time. Regards.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us an anonimized dataset? This would help us to optimize the query further. I would also expect this query be faster.
If it is possible please send it to michael@arangodb.com Thanks a lot.