# Find all paths between two vertices

Tags: arangodb

How can I get all paths between two vertices with a depth of n in arangodb 3.1?
The only possibility that I found in the AQL documentation was the shortest path. But I would like to get all paths, not only the shortest one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677086/arangodb-how-to-get-all-the-possible-paths-between-2-vertices

Comment: Thanks @kyle But this is not working for arangodb 3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get all paths with exactly length `n` between to vertices with known `_id` values you can use the following AQL statement:

```
FOR target, unused, path IN @depth ANY @source edgeCollection
  FILTER target._id == @target
  RETURN path
```

Let me shortly explain the parts:

- `FOR target, unused, path` => defines return values: `target` = vertex you search for, `unused` = last edge pointing to it, `path` = the complete path in format: `{edges: [edge1, edge2, ..], vertices: [vertex1, vertex2, ...]}`
- `IN @depth` => Define the exact depth `n` no shorter and no longer paths will be returned. Can also be `@min..@max` than all paths with length min to max will be returned.
- `ANY` => Search direction, this will ignore direction of edges, can also be `INBOUND` or `OUTBOUND`
- `@source` => The target vertex id
- `edgeCollection` => name of the edge collection, can also be `GRAPH "graphName"`
- `FILTER target._id == @target` => Here we validate that we find the correct vertex.
- `RETURN path` => Well return the Path ;)

Comment: Thanks @mchacki ! That is what is was looking for! I thought the first parameter target contains all vertex of the result.